# TextInputLayout Error: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Tags: android

I've been surfing the web for a while trying to resolve this error: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout, ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList

I've already added the correct dependency to the file: implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0' and I can't really think of what else to try...

```
2019-12-17 17:48:19.649 3698-9390/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.microdetection.d.k.a(SourceFile:91)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.microdetection.d.l.run(Unknown Source:14)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.a.b(SourceFile:32)
        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.runner.a.c.call(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.j(SourceFile:103)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:17)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.g.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.aw.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.b.i.run(SourceFile:6)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/reg_display_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_label">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/display_name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/reg_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/register_display_name">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/reg_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/register_email">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reg_create_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/create_account"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_password" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
Code

package com.hfad.messengerapp5;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private EditText mDisplayName;
    private EditText mEmail;
    private EditText mPassword;
    private Button mCreateBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        // Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Android Fields
        mDisplayName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_display_name);
        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        mCreateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg_create_btn);

        mCreateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String display_name = mDisplayName.getText().toString();
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

                register_user(display_name, email, password);
            }
        });
    }

    private void register_user(String display_name, String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display message to user
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: That stack trace is not from the given Exception. You want the section with the `ClassNotFoundException` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using AndroidX 
so you have to use

```
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

**So replace**

```
android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

with

```
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

**And use**

```
implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.0.0-alpha1'
```

as gradle dependency because com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout belongs to this dependency.